# Find values that each subarray of an array contains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I've got an `Array` of arrays. There can be two or more subarrays:

```
array = [
  ["66892885", "66891801", "66924833", "66892255"],
  ["65167829", "65167828", "66924833"],
  ["66924833", "66891801"]
]
```

I need only the values found across each subarray. So in this case `"66924833"` would be the only match. For a value to show up in the result, each subarray has to contain it.

How can I do this?

Comment: what would the return be if there are more than 2 sub arrays?

Comment: @lusketeer even if there are 10 sub arrays, I still need the shared values across all 10

Comment: so for `[[a, b], [b, c], [a, c]]` would return `[]`?

Comment: @lusketeer yes...but the way my data is configured, there will ALWAYS be a match

Comment: okay, someone already posted what I wanted to post, should work for your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) with Array's [Set Intersection (`#&`)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-26) method like this

```
array.inject(:&)
```

to get the desired result:

```
array=[["66892885", "66891801", "66924833", "66892255", "1", "33"],
       ["65167829", "65167828", "66924833", "1", "33", "44"], 
       ["2344", "66924833", "1", "33"]]

array.inject(:&)
#=>["66924833", "1", "33"]
```

Comment: Since `&` has special meaning in Ruby's syntax, it might be worth noting that here `:&` is merely a symbol referring to the operator method [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-26). So `[a, b, c].inject(:&)` translates to `a & b & c`